# Show terminal status in a Tkinter widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using python2.7.10 on MacOs Sierra and have created a rsync over ssh connection with my raspberrypi. The Idea is to synchronize my local folder with my remote folder on the raspberrypi.

My function syncroFolder() is working fine, but how can I show the real time status on my tkinter window ? is there any easy solution ? I can't understand the question posted: "Redirect command line results to a tkinter GUI"

```
def syncroFolder():
    os.system("rsync -avz -e \"ssh -p port\" /source/path /folder/to/rcync ")
```

Thank you for your help

---

2017-09-05:
I managed to write the result in a file with the "| tee " my command looks like this now

```
os.system("rsync -avzr -P --info=progress2 -e \"ssh -p %s\" %s %s | tee %s & "  %(port,dossier,destination,exampleOutputTxtAdd))
```

I have created a textbox in TKinter that display the last line of the file

```
status, lastLineInFile = commands.getstatusoutput("tail -n 1 "+ exampleOutputTxtAdd)
T.insert(END,'Transfering: \n'+lastLineInFile)
```

The output file looks like this:

```
sending incremental file list
folder/

          0   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#0, to-chk=397/410)
folder/Bigfile.avi

     32,768   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  
  2,555,904   0%    2.39MB/s    0:07:18  
  3,112,960   0%    1.41MB/s    0:12:23  
  3,637,248   0%    1.11MB/s    0:15:44
```

but the textbox shows all those lines

```
  Transfering

      3,776   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 

 16,567,040   1%   13.69MB/s    0:01:15
```

and keep adding lines, even if I read the -n = 1 line of the output file.

I have been trying to use the --out-format=\"%t %o %f %b\", but then I have the status only after transfer (in case of a big file)... I tried many options and none worked for me... I don't understand why it doesn't display only the last line of the output file.
Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: You should be able to write the data line by line to a text box with a timed loop. That should be simple enough.

Comment: but when the program runs the command rsync, the results appear in the Terminal and the program (Tkinter window) freezes, until the synchronization is finished. I read the thread are not a good idea with Tkinter. In my case, the timed loop works only if before (but then it doesn't run rsync). I will keep trying... anyway, thanks

Comment: /so you sync the data to a file and then have a timed loop that reads that file in read only mode and use that to keep your tkinter text box updated with current data. This should prevent any issues you are having. If you need to separate the sync command then you may need to look into multiprocessing with tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using python3 (because that's what I have). The essence is as in the references example to use a thread to read the pipe line by line into a queue and then use an after event to read the queue. Enhancements would be to read all items from the queue each time and stop the after event sequence once the subprocess has halted. Test using `python3 tkinter_rsync.py rsync://servername/sharename` or something like that.

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue, Empty

def read_pipe(widget, queue):
    interval = 1
    try:
        line = queue.get_nowait()
    except Empty:
        interval = 5
        pass
    else:
        widget.insert('end', line)
    widget.after(interval, lambda: read_pipe(widget, queue))

def queue_line(pipe, queue):
    for line in iter(pipe.readline, b''):
        queue.put(line)
    pipe.close()

def main(argv):
    root = tk.Tk()
    text = tk.Text(root)
    vs = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical', command=text.yview)
    text.configure(yscrollcommand=vs.set)
    text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')
    vs.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    process = Popen(['rsync', '--list-only', argv[1]], stdout=PIPE)
    queue = Queue()
    tid = Thread(target=queue_line, args=(process.stdout, queue))
    tid.daemon = True
    tid.start()

    root.after(0, lambda: read_pipe(text, queue))
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Why not `widget.after(interval, lambda: read_pipe(widget, queue))` => `widget.after(interval, read_pipe, widget, queue)`?