# Python, Tkinter, using subprocess Popen, running external program

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, stdout, popen

Firstly I am python begginer, so I need lots of advises from many people.

I am working on making a GUI program that runs with another external program simultaneously.

and the external program runs depending on user command line input.

its command line is not same with shell or python. It has its own command line.

here is the looking of the external program.

[image: the left one is my GUI program, and the right one is the external program that runs based on its own command line arguments]

so far i was able to run the external program using subprocess.Popen, but I did not use stdin, stdout, stderr arguments with PIPE opended, which means that i did not connected this external program with another one. it just runs independently, with no communication with others.

but here is the problem

i want to embed the terminal into the GUI program, so that it can communicate with the external program.

So I inserted text frame and entry frame into my GUI program, and tried to integrate the GUI program and external program altogether.

For this to be achieved, I added (stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) options in subprocess.Popen instance.

However the problem is that the external program terminates immediately when the subprocess.Popen starts its job. [image: the external program terminates immediately when it runs based on subprocess.Popen with stdin, stdout, stderr options]

this problem did not happen when i did not add stdin, stdout, stderr options.

I also think i need to explain about this external program

the external program is based on C++ language. So i want to explain the basic mechanism of this program.

This program waits for user input with while(1) infinite loop. And it does several jobs based on in-built command line arguments.

So the external program suppose to run continuously, not to terminate immediately since it works based on while(1) infinite loop and user input.

here is my code

```
def main_window():

        root = Tk()

        root.title("Seoul Cell")
        root.geometry("1300x1000")
        root.resizable(True, True)
            
        global monitor1
        monitor1 = Layout(root)
        monitor1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # 메뉴바 생성
        menu = Menu(root)
        root.config(menu=menu)

        menu_file = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
        menu_file.add_command(label="Open Cell Information", command = open_cell_info)
        menu_file.add_command(label="Partitioning", command = open_partition_info)
        menu_file.add_command(label="Pairing", command= open_pairing)
        menu_file.add_command(label="Placement", command = open_placement)
        menu_file.add_command(label="Routing", command = open_routing)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Result Display", menu = menu_file )

        menu_file2 = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
        menu_file2.add_command(label="Live result from program", command= live_work)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Live Result Display", menu = menu_file2)

        menu_work = Menu(menu, tearoff= 0)
        menu_work.add_command(label="Open layerinfo file", command= open_layerinfo)
        menu_work.add_command(label="save as layerinfo.txt", command = save_as)
        menu.add_cascade(label="TechInfo", menu = menu_work)

        # 2번째 메뉴바

        menu2_frame = Frame(root)
        menu2_frame.pack(fill = "x")
        layer_but = Button(menu2_frame, text = "Layers", command = open_window)
        layer_but.pack(side = "left", padx=3, pady=3)

        # Script

        script_frame = LabelFrame(root, text = "script")
        script_frame.pack(fill='x', side="bottom",padx=10, pady=10)

        script_menu_frame = Frame(script_frame)
        script_menu_frame.pack(fill='x')

        # Script Text box

        scrollbar_script = Scrollbar(script_frame)
        scrollbar_script.pack(side='right',fill="y")


        global script
        script = Text(script_frame, height=10, yscrollcommand=scrollbar_script.set)
        script.pack(fill='x', side="bottom", padx=5, pady=5)
        scrollbar_script.config(command=script.yview)

        process_exe = exe_program()

        root.mainloop()


def exe_program():

    top = Tk()
    top.title('program')
    top.geometry("600x400")

    program = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = 'Choose the execution File')
    process_exe = subprocess.Popen(program, stdin= subprocess.PIPE, stdout= subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines= True)
    (out, err) = process_exe.communicate()
    print(out)

    top.mainloop()

    return process_exe




if __name__ == '__main__':

    main_window()
```

I desperately need help

thanks everyone for reading my work

Comment: Shouldn't you put the `Popen` in a new thread and keep calling `process_exe.communicate()`? Right now, you start the process, read from it and just print out whatever is in the `stdout` of that process.

Comment: A UI application must continually process it's events. You can't stop that while you wait for a child process so you need to run the child on a worker thread. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46058714/291641 for an example of this.